# invalid app id while trying to implement facebook login

Tags: android, xml, facebook

Hi guys i'm trying to get my app (very basic atm) to include a FB login but I keep getting: **invalid app id** whenever I click my on my log in with facebook button. I've done the hash correctly (or so I believe and have registered with my fb dev account). Here is my mainfest: `

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.examples.sebastianshelley.jump" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And here's my strings.xml file with the app_id hash:

```
    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">Jump</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="Facebook">Facebook</string>
    <string name="app_id">KVjqf5zxlsetd9RzUzs0Xhw8WtE=</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main_activity2">MainActivity2Activity</string>
    <string name="facebookButton">Facebook</string>
</resources>
```

Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app_id given by you is not valid one. App Id will be **like** this : 1234567890. I believe app_id mentioned by you is the Key_hash for your keystore.

You can read more here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started